# Submitting form depend of color clicked

Tags: javascript, php, html, form-submit

i have form that's announcing user for error, warning or new content on my site. I have three buttons on class `ann-right` and each button have its color. When i click the button, the button input on class `ann-left` changed to color were clicked. What i want to ask is, how do i submit the form depend of color selected. Red is for "Error announcement", Green is for "Warning announcement" and Blue is for "New announcement". `Red = #D91E18`
`Green = #3FC380`
`Blue = #5BBBFF`

```
  <div class="ann-left">
  <form method="post" id="ann">
     <input id="announce-text" type="text" name="" placeholder="What's new?"></input>
     <input id="submit-post" type="button" name="" onsubmit="submitform();" value="Post"></input>
  </form>
  </div>
  <div class="ann-right">
   <button id="red" onclick="color1()" class="tooltip color" title="Error!"></button>
   <button id="green" onclick="color2()" class="tooltip color"title="Warning!" ></button>
   <button id="blue" onclick="color3()" class="tooltip color" title="New!"></button>
  </div>

<script>  
function color1() {
  document.getElementById("submit-post").style.backgroundColor = "#D91E18";
  sessionStorage.setItem('col1', "#D91E18");
}
function color2() {
  document.getElementById("submit-post").style.backgroundColor = "#3FC380";
  sessionStorage.setItem('col2', "#3FC380");
}
function color3() {
  document.getElementById("submit-post").style.backgroundColor = "#5BBBFF";
  sessionStorage.setItem('col3', "#5BBBFF");
}

color1(sessionStorage.getItem('col1'));
color2(sessionStorage.getItem('col2'));
color3(sessionStorage.getItem('col3'));

function submitform() {
}
</script>
```

Comment: what's the relation to php? if it's not related, you should remove the tag for it.

Comment: What's the question ?

Comment: have you tried adding a "submit" to each function or setting a value of a hidden field to whichever you would like?

Comment: *"how do i submit the form depend of color selected"* - Oh I see how this could be php-related. You want to pass those to php, correct? If so, then the question is both unclear and too broad.

Comment: if i understand the question, you want to submit to a different page based on the selected color ? If so, you can change the action of the form using javascript on color selection

Comment: After reading their question again, I think the php tag for the pending edit http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14772119 shouldn't be removed; it may have relevance to what they're asking.

Comment: So clicking "New announcement" will submit the form?

Comment: You need to answer to comments here, otherwise you'll lose a lot of your present audience.

Comment: @Fred-ii- based on the current question, there is no php code and the answer seems to be JS related but perhaps i did not understand the question and the PHP tag is relevant but in this case i think the question needs to be clarified

Comment: oops sorry, it should be html thanks for edit.

Comment: @Crozet yes, i want to submit a post depend of color selected, when the red color selected, in another .html page will show "announcement" that something error in our site. Green color show warning and Blue color show new content.

Comment: @d.coder no, i mean when i submit the form it will show annoucement depend on color it is.

Comment: @Fred-ii- i do :)

Comment: @happymacarts i've tried using if statement, but i don't know how to use hidden field value, how do i implement that ?

Comment: @Crozet OP states: *"how do i submit the form depend of color selected"* - to which they responded with *"I do"*. They're wanting to be able to pull the selected items and to be used in a PHP handler.

Comment: @GilangRizkie That's what I thought. See Antonio's answer below http://stackoverflow.com/a/41447336/1415724 seems to have answered it completely, right? Unless you already had your php handler?

Comment: @GilangRizkie I added the php tag back in, since there is relevance to the question.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Exactly.. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use one input hidden to pass the type of annoncement to your form.
Then you submit it normally.

```
  <div class="ann-left">
  <form method="post" action="announcement_post.php" id="ann">
     <input type="text" name="announcement_description" id="announce-text"  placeholder="What's new?">
     <input type="hidden" name="announcement_type" id="announcement_type">
     <input id="submit-post" type="submit" name="" value="Post">
  </form>
  </div>
  <div class="ann-right">
   <button id="red" onclick="color1()" class="tooltip color" title="Error!">&nbsp;</button>
   <button id="green" onclick="color2()" class="tooltip color"title="Warning!" >&nbsp;</button>
   <button id="blue" onclick="color3()" class="tooltip color" title="New!">&nbsp;</button>
  </div>

<script>  
function color1() {
  document.getElementById("submit-post").style.backgroundColor = "#D91E18";
   document.getElementById("announcement_type").value="Error announcement";
  sessionStorage.setItem('col1', "#D91E18");
}
function color2() {
  document.getElementById("submit-post").style.backgroundColor = "#3FC380";
   document.getElementById("announcement_type").value="Warning announcement";  
  sessionStorage.setItem('col2', "#3FC380");
}
function color3() {
  document.getElementById("submit-post").style.backgroundColor = "#5BBBFF";
   document.getElementById("announcement_type").value="New announcement";   
  sessionStorage.setItem('col3', "#5BBBFF");
}

color1(sessionStorage.getItem('col1'));
color2(sessionStorage.getItem('col2'));
color3(sessionStorage.getItem('col3'));

</script>
```

**announcement_post.php:**

```
<?php

if(!isset($_POST["announcement_type"])) die("Post was not sent.");

echo $_POST["announcement_type"];
echo '<br>';
echo $_POST["announcement_description"];
```

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of issues here. First you are not practicing DRY (Dont Repeat Yourself), which is very important when creating functions. Create one function that handles your setColor function and send the selected colors on the actual buttons clicked. Once thats done, you can focus on "submitting your form". When you submit a form it normally expects you to have a buttom with type `submit`. Since you dont have that, it will not submit the form. What I would do is place your `onsubmit()` on the form element as such:

```
<div class="ann-left">
    <form method="post" id="ann" onsubmit="return submitform(this);">
        <input id="hidden-input" type="hidden" name="color_selected" value="">
        <input id="announce-text" type="text" name="" placeholder="What's new?">
        <input id="submit-post" type="submit" name=""  value="Post">
    </form>
</div>
<div class="ann-right">
    <button id="red" onclick="setColor('#D91E18')" class="tooltip color" title="Error!"></button>
    <button id="green" onclick="setColor('#3FC380')" class="tooltip color"title="Warning!" ></button>
    <button id="blue" onclick="setColor('#5BBBFF')" class="tooltip color" title="New!"></button>
</div>

<script>
    var $btn = document.getElementById("submit-post");
    var $hidden = document.getElementById("hidden-input");

    function setColor(color) {
        $btn.style.backgroundColor = color;
        $hidden.value = color;
    }

    function submitform(form) {
        alert(form.color_selected.value);
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I feel the question goes further than this. Pretty sure they want to take the selected values and pass those on to a PHP handler.

Comment: I'm practicing DRY, i was using this `function color1(col) {
    document.getElementById("submit-post").style.backgroundColor = col;
    sessionStorage.setItem('col1', col);
  }
  
  color1(sessionStorage.getItem('col1'));` but, it was quitely hard how to implement to wht u do... Btw thanks! its solving my problem :D

Comment: i don't understand the point of using javascript to set the color value, the easiest solution seems to be radio buttons

Comment: cool.. guess you would still need JS in order to change the submit btn color.

Comment: @GilangRizkie Ok, so the php tag wasn't needed after all, correct? This suggests that you already have your php handler, right?

Comment: Follow the @AntonioAlexandreAlonsodeSi 's answer for the PHP side of things.

Comment: @Crozet the reason i'm not using radio is uncustomized.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function color1() {
  document.getElementById("submit-post").style.backgroundColor = "#D91E18";
  sessionStorage.setItem('col1', "#D91E18");
  document.getElementById("hidden_field").value = 'error';
  submitform();
}

function color2() {
  document.getElementById("submit-post").style.backgroundColor = "#3FC380";
  sessionStorage.setItem('col2', "#3FC380");
  document.getElementById("hidden_field").value = 'warning';
  submitform();
}

function color3() {
  document.getElementById("submit-post").style.backgroundColor = "#5BBBFF";
  sessionStorage.setItem('col3', "#5BBBFF");
  document.getElementById("hidden_field").value = 'new';
  submitform();
}

color1(sessionStorage.getItem('col1'));
color2(sessionStorage.getItem('col2'));
color3(sessionStorage.getItem('col3'));

function submitform() {
  var form = document.getElementById("ann");
  var data = new FormData(form);
  console.log(data);
  //var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  //eq.send(data);
  form.submit();

}
```

```css
#red {
  background: #D91E18;
}
#green {
  background: #3fc380;
}
#blue {
  background: #5bbbff;
}
```

```html
<form method="post" id="ann">
  <div class="ann-left">

    <input id="announce-text" type="text" name="" placeholder="What's new?" />
    <input id="submit-post" type="button" name="" onsubmit="submitform();" value="Post" />
    <input type="hidden" id="hidden_field" />
  </div>
  <div class="ann-right">
    <button id="red" onclick="color1()" class="tooltip color" title="Error!"></button>
    <button id="green" onclick="color2()" class="tooltip color" title="Warning!"></button>
    <button id="blue" onclick="color3()" class="tooltip color" title="New!"></button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help sir :)